# Is $f(x,y)=-xy$ neither concave nor convex?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, optimization, convex-analysis

Is $f(x,y)=-xy$ neither concave nor convex? I used the definition for first differentiable functions and determined it depends on the choice of points, hence it is neither.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, and it would be obtained more easily from the 2nd derivative test. The Hessian matrix of $f$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has negative determinant; hence, the graph is saddle-like at every point.

Comment: It's slightly incorrect to say that graph is saddle-like at every point just because not every point of $xy$-plane is critical. When gradient doesn't vanish at point then function is affine locally so there's no to call this point saddle :)

Comment: Hence, "is saddle-like" and not "has a saddle point". This is a geometric property of the surface, independent of the orientation of coordinate system ("saddle surface").